# How to add ajax live search rotating icon

Tags: jquery

I have written a jquery ui auto complete. I noticed that it takes time to get data from remoteserver.
Therefore, to keep user waiting I need to use ajax live search icon to rotate.

[live search](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp)

Problem is I don't have a idear of how it works.

I found this code.

```
.ui-autocomplete-loading
 {
    background: white url('images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif') right center no-repeat;
 }
```

How to do this with Jquery UI?

Comment: You know there is a link called 'view source' on that page right?

Answer (score 1):

Not very clear what is the problem.
Generally, the idea is to add .gif image before (or when started) request and then remove it after it is done. For example:

```
$(".example-search-input").addClass("ui-autocomplete-loading");
$.ajax({
//request
}).done(function() {
    $(".example-search-input").removeClass("ui-autocomple-loading");
});
```

In your particular case it is done with this code in file `jquery-ui.js`:

```
search: function( value, event ) {
    value = value != null ? value : this._value();

    // always save the actual value, not the one passed as an argument
    this.term = this._value();

    if ( value.length < this.options.minLength ) {
        return this.close( event );
    }

    if ( this._trigger( "search", event ) === false ) {
        return;
    }

    return this._search( value );
},

_search: function( value ) {
    this.pending++;
    this.element.addClass( "ui-autocomplete-loading" );
    this.cancelSearch = false;

    this.source( { term: value }, this._response() );
},

_response: function() {
    var that = this,
        index = ++requestIndex;

    return function( content ) {
        if ( index === requestIndex ) {
            that.__response( content );
        }

        that.pending--;
        if ( !that.pending ) {
            that.element.removeClass( "ui-autocomplete-loading" );
        }
    };
},
```

Tip: you can use Chrome's Developer Tools to catch the code you need. Click right button on the input field, then click "Inspect Element", then click on the chosen element right button again and you can choose "Break on" to get it break on any modifications of this element. When in it breaks, you can find trace on the right side of the Dev Tools which will allow you to find what code was executed.

UPD: In my answer I assumed that you have the .gif image in the correct directory. If not, you can see where it tries to load image from by checking Google Chrome Developer Tools Console (Shift + Ctrl + J) or in the "Network" tab of the Dev Tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you give the image path properly then it gets added automatically.

Have look at demo here: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EH5qh/4/)

```
.ui-autocomplete-loading {
background: white url('http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/css/themes/default/images/ajax-loader.gif') right center no-repeat;
}
#city { width: 25em; }
```

I have given the below path for image:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/css/themes/default/images/ajax-loader.gif

You can see this image while retrieving the data from server after entering each character in textbox.